# Trying to continously send async data to the browser: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, async-await

I have function `queryIterator` that returns async object value called `result`, I use a call back function to send `result` to the browser via `res.send()`.

> **Error:** (node:3497) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

I think im getting error because i am consistently resending a response to the browser when the header is already set, correct?

**How can I continuously stream data to the client browser from express server?**

```
  router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    // Assign first query
    searchedT = req.body.searchTerm;
    queries.push(req.body.searchTerm);
    // Invoke the async iterator
    console.log("start....");
    const results = await queryIterator(queries, async function(result) {
      console.log("--->" + await result);
      res.send(await result);

    });
    // res.send(result);
});


async function queryIterator(queries, callback) {
  for await (const result of queryGenerator()) {
      // console.log('Iterating... ', result);
      // console.log(`On Queue Searches #${++counter}: `, queries);
      // console.log(`On Queue Searches LAST #${++counter}: `, queries[queries.length-1]);
       if (!queries.length) {
          console.log("query length is zero");
          return result;
      }
      callback(result);
      // return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you get all the results first then send them?

Comment: Because this is essentially an infinite loop of api calls @PlatinumIndustries

Comment: Then why don't you just send the result as a stream?

Comment: or if you want to make a two way connection, you can go for sockets too.

Comment: @AtishayJain New to Javascript and Async, Im not  sure what you mean, can you please demonstrate an example?

Comment: Correct, `send()` sets some headers (like content length), writes a body, and ends the response. You can't do this multiple times. Use `write` instead.

Comment: @Bergi Getting this: (node:3180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object

Comment: when Changed to this:       res.write(await result);

Comment: You should not use an `async function` as a callback, and there's no need to `await` the `result`. But you need to convert it to a string - maybe `JSON.stringify()`? I don't know what kind of stream you want.

Comment: @Bergi the problem with write is it shows results after the post is complete i.e. status 200.. i want it to be streams as i get the values

Comment: What do you mean by "*after the post is complete*"? How are you consuming the API, with [`EventSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events)? Or no JS client at all?

Comment: @Bergi After the post request is complete meaning its a form with POST method, that says, search tweets on twitter. The twitter API has an npm module with node, using basically that to request tweets, now want to stream the tweets to the browser - as I get them async data,